# Ubuntu 19.10 - release hour?

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I was just about to install 19.04 when I found out that new release is coming just today. I was wondering if anyone of you know what time exactly is the release going to be downloadable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There was [a message yesterday](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-19-10-final-call-for-testing/12995) which indicates that it may be slightly delayed. I don't think anybody is able to answer your question ATM. It may well show up later today as planned - or not.

Comment: Visit https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop once an hour! I would expect something here as well: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/

Comment: I would leave out the notify-send in case OP doesn't have libnotify-bin (or libnotify4?) which, IIRC, isn't installed by default and is needed for `notify-send` to work.

Comment: The exact time would depend on how quickly mirrors across the world can be seeded.

Comment: its is out http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/

Comment: You can get the files at the [iso-testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/407/builds). Those in bold text are accepted for publlshing, for example Lubuntu Eoan as 19.10.

Comment: why ask? I installed it a week ago :P

Comment: Reviewers: I'm inclined to think this isn't "a problem that can't be reproduced." 19.10 not yet being released won't happen again. But knowledge of *precisely when* it came out will exist and remain of interest in connection with Ubuntu release engineering and history. I don't know if that's a strong enough reason to consider this on-topic. But closing a question as "no repro" that is about something of interest to much of the Ubuntu community doesn't seem right to me. The best approach may be to close this as a duplicate of a broader question about all versions' release times, if we have one.

Answer (score 6):

It's out--everyone can go get it now!

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/

Specifically, as of 2019-10-17 at 14:39 (UTC), all the files for Ubuntu 19.10 became available at that location. Soon afterward, http://releases.ubuntu.com/ was updated so it no longer referred to 19.10 as a beta.

Although [the download page at ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/#download) has not yet been updated to show it, it has been released, and the main website will likely be updated soon.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop shows 19.10 now.

Answer (score 0):

*For future Googler's:*

If you already have Ubuntu, just run the following command to trigger the distribution upgrade:

`update-manager -d`

[image]